# Why does windows-xp setting environment variable to %USERPROFILE% return the wrong path

Tags: windows-xp, environment-variables

I am trying to set `HOME` to be `%USEPROFILE%` for the currently logged on user. However, creating a system environment variable `HOME` and setting to and setting it `%USERPROFILE%` does not seem to work.  After logging out and logging in as a non-administrative user, I have

```
c:\ set
...
HOME=c:\Documents and Settings\administrator
HOMEPATH=c:\Documents and Settings\[user]
...
```

In the Windows Environment Variables dialog, I have

```
HOME   %USERPROFILE%
```

but don't see `HOMEPATH` anywhere.  Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

Comment: How exactly do you set the `HOME` variable to `USERPROFILE`? It may have been litterally set to the string `"%USERPROFILE"`.

Comment: @hesse: The *Environment Variables* dialog adds registry values of type REG_EXPAND_SZ (as opposed to REG_SZ), allowing such expansion.

Answer (score 1):

It is a little unclear from your question, but it sounds like the problem is that the `HOME` environment variable is being assigned the expanded value of `%userprofile%` (`c:\Documents and Settings\administrator`) at time of configuring it, rather than being stored as the string literal `%userprofile%` which would be expanded after login.

It's been a while since I worked with this sort of thing on XP, bu if I recall, permanent environment variables are stored in the registry.

`set` usually only works in the current cmd session, so to get it to be across all sessions,there is a `setx` util (from Microsoft) that will permanently set env variables.

One trick is to make a batch file which runs at startup (put it in the startup folder of `all users`) which runs `setx`. This will ensure that `%userprofile%` expands to the currently logged in user's profile.

Comment: Just wanted to add that BATCH files are simple script files having the extension `.bat`. Simply put the commands you normally run in `cmd` in this file and when executed, all the commands will run as if you ran them from `cmd`.

Comment: @horatio I would the value of `HOME` to be set to the the location of the currently logged in user's profile directory is (ie value of `%USERPROFILE%`). Does that make sense?

Comment: @horatio the batch file work around does not work either.  Testing indicated that `HOME` is being set to the previous logged-in user's `%USERPROFILE%`.

Comment: You would be setting the value of `HOME` every time a user logs in. If `HOME` is set, you might need to unset it first not sure, and you will need to SET it in such a way that it stays SET until logging off. Normally, any environment variables created using SET will go away as soon as the cmd window (or batch file process) is closed. `Setx` works around this. see, for instance ( http://ss64.com/nt/setx.html )

Comment: @horatio thanks for the clarifications.  I was originally setting `HOME` using Windows Environment Variables dialog box (under System Properties -> Advanced ->Environment Variable). I also tested your suggestions of a BAT file in All Users->Startup folder with the single line `setx HOME=%USERPROFILE%`. Both seem to set `HOME` to the previous logged in users profilfe directory.

Comment: if %USERPROFILE% evaluates to the wrong location, then there is something wrong with your configuration.